# Syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am getting this error message: `line 12: 470 + : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+ ")`

I still get my answer of 470 at the end but this error message display in the output and I cannot understand why. Can any one please explain?

Here is my code:

```
while IFS= read -r var
do
total=$(($total+$var))
done<"$input"

 

echo "The total is = $total";
echo
```

My final output each time:

```
 line 12: 470 + : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+ ")
The total is = 470
```

Comment: This is because `$var` is empty in that last iteration of the loop. The file probably ends with a blank line

Comment: I don't understand how I correct it, do I end it differently?

Comment: you could check if `$var` is empty before using it

Comment: in the case of a blank line (ie, `${var}` is undefined) you could default `${var}` to 0: `${var:-0}`

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `$` with a dereference inside an arithmetic expression, that prevents special arithmetic parsing rules (that treat an empty string as a 0) from being able to apply. Just take out the `$`s on the inside to fix your problem:

```
while IFS= read -r var; do
  total=$((total+var))
done <"$input"
```

...or, for clearer (but bash-only) syntax:

```
while IFS read -r var; do
  (( total += var ))
done <"$input"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on other comments, I would change to this to ignore empty lines and whitespace. I don't have your $input file, so I am just entering data directly in the shell and ending my data entry with the EOF indicator (<CTRL>d for me)

```
$ total=0;while IFS= read -r var; do [[ -n "${var##*\ }" ]] && total=$(($total+$var)) ; done

1

2
3

^D
$ echo ${total}
6
```